# Firebase and minio integration

Tags: firebase, minio, minio-client

I am interested in the following. Please tell me, is it possible to configure Firebase in such a way that it automatically uploads documents to Minio. Or is this something that needs to be handled at the code level?

I tried to google this information, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple configuration that you can enable for this.

When you say "documents" I assume you're talking about Firestore documents. You can certainly write your own code to implement this, perhaps using [Cloud Functions Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd) to know when a document changes, then take action on that.

Or if you're talking about objects in Cloud Storage, you can use [Cloud Storage triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events?gen=2nd) as well.